# Fetch curl response and show in Azure devops yaml pipeline parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a task to make a REST call and show the response as a drop-down in the azure pipeline modal window. These values would act as parameters in the pipeline stages.

Any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated.

One approch I tried is to Run a powershell script and try access the output in the Parameter section of the yaml file. [But could not achieve it]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the runtime parameters are set before running the pipeline. It is not possible to dynamically set parameters during the pipeline is running.

For your case, you can try one of the following ways.

##### Try to trigger the pipeline via REST API and pass the response to the parameter.

After running the REST API call and get its response, you can use Azure DevOps REST API "[**Runs - Run Pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to trigger the pipeline and pass the response of previous API call as the value of the parameter in the request body of the Azure DevOps REST API.

```json
{
    . . .
    "templateParameters": {
        "{parameterName}": "{parameterValue}"
    },
    . . .
}
```

- Replace **`{parameterName}`** with the actual name of the runtime parameter you want to set for the pipeline.
- Replace **`{parameterValue}`** with the actual value (response of previous API call).
- If the parameter with the same name has predefined in the YAML file of the pipeline, the Azure DevOps REST API will override the original value with the new one set in the request body (response of previous API call).
- If the parameter has not predefined, the REST API will create a new parameter for the current triggered pipeline run.

##### Pass the response to a pipeline variable during the pipeline running time.

In the pipeline, you can add a stage as the first one. In this stage, you can run the API call to get its response and use the logging comment "[**SetVariable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)" to set the response as an output variable.

```bash
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable={varName};isoutput=true]{varValue}"
```

- Replace **`{varName}`** with the actual variable name you like.
- Replace **`{varValue}`** with the actual value (response of previous API call).

In the same pipeline, set other stages which need to use the response to depend on the first stage so that they can use the output variable from it (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage)).